# play test nullpoint exception

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I run play(1.2.5) test in terminal 
and visit localhost/@tests 
that page says

```
 Oops: NullPointerException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception NullPointerException:
null
```

then following error stack is printed in terminal

```
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /@tests

Oops: NullPointerException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception NullPointerException: null

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:556)
    at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:642)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:198)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:478)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:282)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:426)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:516)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: well, looks like a null pointer exception, huh?  how about some more detail on what your code is trying to do?

Comment: I did nothing but only run play test, and go to chrome to localhost:9000/@tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found how to get ride of this exception. because I have a file with two classes.like

Foo.java:

```
public class Foo {}
class Bar{}
```

Then I rewrite the Bar class as a nested class, every thing is ok!
Thoung I didn't know why, seems due to some bug of eclipse java compiler